# Proper way to stop a stream in node-rtsp-stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, rtsp

I have a nodejs server running and  when I make an api request I want to start a new stream and close/stop the old one.
The code for starting a new stream:

```
  Stream = require('node-rtsp-stream');

  this.stream = new Stream({
    name: 'camera-stream',
    streamUrl: 'rtsp://' + camera.cameraUserName + ':' + camera.cameraPassword 
    + '@' + camera.cameraIp,
    wsPort: 9999
  });
```

Who can i close/stop the current stream?

I tried this code:

```
this.stream.mpeg1Muxer.stream.kill();
this.stream.streamUrl = 'rtsp://' + camera.cameraUserName + ':' + 
camera.cameraPassword + '@' + camera.cameraIP + ':554';
this.stream.startMpeg1Stream();
```

I'm not sure that this is the right way to do that.

Comment: `node-rtsp-stream` does not provide a way to kill, but `.stream.kill();` should work

Answer (score 2):

Look inside the source code and you will find VideoStream.prototype.stop = function () {....} 
and therefore try this -> this.stream.stop();

Answer (score -1):

node-rtsp-stream has been updated to node-rtsp-stream-es6. In the latter, there is a function `.stop()` that you can call to stop the streaming.